# SonarQube warning: Unable to get default branch, defaulting to 'master': TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultBranch' of null

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

We use Azure DevOps and YAML pipelines to build and analyze our code.
This all works fine, except for the code that uses `main` instead of `master` as the default branch name. Then SonarQube emits a warning: `Unable to get default branch, defaulting to 'master': TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultBranch' of null`
The warning is a false-positive. When I go to the SonarQube portal everything looks fine for the project and it even displays the default branch is `main`.

We have a 'no warnings' policy, so it is very sad SonarQube is emitting this warning, which should be in my opinion `Information`.

I think I need to instruct SonarQube not to look for the `master` branch or tell it to also look for the `main` branch. But I can't figure out how to do this. The documentation is not very helpful at this point.

This is my yaml task:

```yaml
  - task: SonarQubePrepare@5
    displayName: Prepare analysis on SonarQube ($(SonarProjectKey))
    inputs:
      SonarQube: 'SonarQube - Developer Edition'
      projectKey: $(SonarProjectKey)
      projectName: '${{ parameters.AnalyseProjectName }}'
      projectVersion: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
      extraProperties: |
        sonar.verbose=true
        sonar.branch.name=$(Build.SourceBranchName)
        sonar.branch.target=main
        sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths=**/coverage.opencover.xml
        sonar.cs.vscoveragexml.reportsPaths=$(Agent.BuildDirectory)\TestResults\*.coveragexml
        sonar.exclusions=**\Tests\**\*, **\TestApps\**\*, **\GlobalSuppressions.cs
```

If needed I can make changes to our build agents.

Please advise.

Comment: I also asked this at the Sonar Community: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/unable-to-get-default-branch-defaulting-to-master-typeerror-cannot-read-property-defaultbranch/97789 But no solution from there either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following an extensive discussion with the SonarQube team, they have recently released a minor update to their Azure DevOps (AZDO) extension. I'm pleased to inform you that this new version has resolved the issue and no longer reports the warning.